# Issue in pause/resume for thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am playing one lyrics thread and I want to pause this thread when user clicks on pause button, the variable is assigned false value in `onPause()` method of `activity` lifecycle. Now if I try to pause the thread in the middle of the poem and resume it then it should start from where I left, but it starts from first line, not from where I left. When counter is 0, thread has been stopped by putting boolean variable (ringa_thread_running) false.
Now when I press the button to resume the thread, it doesn't work, rather the displayed line/lyrics is fixed on the screen.

Also `resume()` method for thread has been deprecated. Here `start()` method cannot be used, when I tried to use start method, it gave out **Fatal Error**: Thread already started.

**Below is my code.**

```
pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                ringa_thread_running=false;
                pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                counter = 1;
            } else if (counter == 1) {
                ringa_thread_running=true;
                lyrics_ring.resume();
                pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it by sleep thread and then use notify to wake it up

Comment: It didn't work for me, I tried another method which worked for me.

Comment: can you share it. May be it will be useful for me too.

Comment: Hello,
I am not able to post in comment here, code exceeding the mentioned word limit. Sound issue got fixed, but text issue is still remaining, not able to sync with sound.